# permission denied on push to local docker registry on windows10

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-for-windows

I am Using **Windows 10** and here is my daemon conifiguration:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [
    "blah.hub:5000"
  ],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true,
  "allow-nondistributable-artifacts": [
    "blah.hub:5000"
  ]
}
```

also i use **Docker Desktop** and working on **Windows Mode (not Linux)**.

**blah.hub** is a name defined in my etc/hosts file and mapped to my registry machine.

i created private registry by running registry image pulled by this command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v F:/docker-hub/registry:/var/lib/registry  --restart=always --name blah.hub registry
```

by these steps i can successfully access to path http://blah.hub:5000/v2/_catalog .

but when i want to push my tagged image as `blah.hub:5000/myImg` it is not working:

```
docker push blah.hub:5000/myImg
The push refers to repository [blah.hub:5000/myImg]
af0b15c8625b: Retrying in 6 seconds
```

when i explore to registry's container volume shared with registry machine there is folders created in `v2/repositories/myImg/_uploads` that contains a zero-size file named `staredat`.

here is the log for registry container when i push:

```
11.5.2.117 - - [05/Jul/2019:06:42:36 +0000] "POST /v2/myImg/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 500 255 "" "docker/18.09.1 go/go1.10.6 git-commit/4c52b90 os/windows arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.09.1 \\(windows\\))"
time="2019-07-05T06:42:36.4979957Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code=unknown err.detail="filesystem: truncate /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/myImg/_uploads/5c131802-afcc-484b-841b-4eb08a07d7a5/startedat: permission denied" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.11.2 http.request.host="blah.hub:5000" http.request.id=ba0c22c5-4c3d-4426-abe9-3fb609532a9a http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr="10.1.2.117:32186" http.request.uri="/v2/myImg/blobs/uploads/" http.request.useragent="docker/18.09.1 go/go1.10.6 git-commit/4c52b90 os/windows arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.09.1 \(windows\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=34.1269ms http.response.status=500 http.response.written=255 vars.name=myImg
```

any opinion? i missed a configuration??

Comment: I hope you have run `docker login blah.hub:5000` prior to `docker push`

Comment: yes i logged in successfully. my username is in administrators group on registry machine and is a Domain user and is not a Local user for registry machine.

Comment: You need to tag the image with your registry URL, just like `http://blah.hub:5000/v2/_catalog/myImg:tag` and then push it.

Comment: it is not a valid format for image name! the full url for upload will generate by ```docker push``` command!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the folder `"F:/docker-hub/registry"` in your host machine has write permission for the users.

Comment: checked it. i set full control for *everyone* to test and ensure all users have permission to access.

Comment: What is the docker version you have in your machine?

Comment: i use ```18.09.1``` version.

Comment: It is a known issue with Edge version. Upgrade if you are not using a stable version - https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-push-image-to-local-registry/59379